# change delay in CCAnimation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, delay

i would like to know, how can i change delay in CCAnimation?

```
_monstrAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:monstrAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
                self.monstr = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"monstr_%d_1.png", currentLevel]]; 
                self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:_monstrAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
                [self.monstr runAction:self.walkAction];
                [monstrSpriteSheet addChild:self.monstr z:1];
```

this working fine, but i should change the speed of FPS and i do...

> ```
>             [self.monstr stopAllActions];
>             [self.monstr runAction:self.walkAction];
>             [self.monstrAnim setDelay:1];
> ```

but nothing happened...

Comment: When are you running the second bit of code?  Unless you retain the CCAnimation, it is likely to be released once it has run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop your walkAction, then change delay of your animation, then recreate action and run it again. If you will look throw the code of CCAnimate, you will see, that delay between frames from CCAnimation object used only during action creation. So this code

```
[self.monstr stopAllActions];
[self.monstrAnim setDelay:1.f];
self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:_monstrAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
[self.monstr runAction:self.walkAction];
```

will do the trick.

Comment: you are welcome. by the way, I don't know what are you doing in your program, but it is a rare case, where I stored action after running. it will be retained after running and released after complete. from this piece of code, it seems that walkAction property of your class is unnecessary. but this is just IMHO =)